# Reading <input> values as numbers and not strings (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json

Let's assume we have a text-box on the page:

```
<input type="text">
```

The visitor types in some characters, and we read those characters via the `value` property of the text-box.

Now, let's say that the text-box represents a numeric value. I cannot define such a thing on the text-box - its value is always going to be a string value. What I can do is, convert that sting value into a numeric value:

```
Number(input.value)
```

However, the input value is treated as a *StringNumericLiteral*, and not a *NumericLiteral*. That means that these input values are allowed (although they are not numeric literals in JavaScript):

- values with leading zeros (like "000003")
- the "Infinity" value
- values with a plus sign (like "+3")

Now, let us say that - for the sake of the argument - I really want to read the input value as *NumericLiteral*. I don't want numbers with leading zeros or the + sign, etc. I was thinking how I could accomplish this, and this is what I came up with:

```
try  {                  
    var n = JSON.parse('{ "n": ' + this.value + ' }').n;
    if (typeof n !== "number") {
        throw "error";
    }
    // n is a Number value that represents the value of the text-box        
} catch(e) {}
```

This is a simplified version of the code, a live demo is available here:
http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/input-as-number.html

Note: I use try-catch because if the input value is not a valid JSON value, the JSON.parse call will fail (throw an error).

So, what do you think of this method. Does it have flaws?

(One downside is that hex numeric values cannot be read, because JSON does not allow them.)

***I just realized ...***

... that the reason why I was trying to do this was not to actually read the input as a number. What I wanted is to check whether the value complied to the NumericLiteral grammar - which is something that a regexp check can do easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `JSON.parse` you will be processing your value as a [`JSONNumber`](http://sideshowbarker.github.com/es5-spec/#x15.12.1.1) token, not really as a [`NumericLiteral`](http://sideshowbarker.github.com/es5-spec/#x7.8.3).

There are differences between `JSONNumber` and `NumericLiteral`, `JSONNumber` doesn't allow leading zeros (no octals), nor hexadecimal literals, nor a leading dot (`3.`), or the opposite, a dot followed by the fraction digits (`.3`), moreover `JSON.parse` is really buggy across implementations, regarding numeric values, in SpiderMonkey (and in the json2.js library) `JSON.parse('01')` will not throw as one can expect.

You could do validation to ensure the string complies with the `NumericLiteral` grammar, and if it does, you can use either `eval` or the `Function` constructor to really convert your value, for example:

```
var numericLiteral = (function () {
  var numericLiteralSyntax = new RegExp([
    '^0x[\\da-fA-F]+$', // HexIntegerLiteral
    '^0[0-7]+$',        // OctalIntegerLiteral
    '^(?:\\.\\d+|(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?)(?:[eE][+-]?\\d+)?$'//DecimalLiteral
  ].join('|'));

  return function (value) {
    if (typeof value != 'string') { throw TypeError('value must be a String'); }

    if (numericLiteralSyntax.test(value)) {
      return Function('return ' + value)(); // a NumericLiteral, evaluate it
    }
    throw SyntaxError('Invalid NumericLiteral'); // Not a NumericLiteral
  }
})();

numericLiteral('0xFF'); // 255, an HexIntegerLiteral
numericLiteral('2e1'); // 20, DecimalLiteral with ExponentPart
numericLiteral('3.'); // 3
numericLiteral('.3'); // 0.3
numericLiteral('3.1416'); // 3.1416
numericLiteral('00010'); // 8, an OctalIntegerLiteral
```

RegExps for validation are from [SourceText](https://github.com/abozhilov/SourceText/) a JavaScript Utility by [Asen Bozhilov](http://asenbozhilov.com/).

Comment: LOL After submitting my question, I went to the kitchen to make me a sandwich and while I was doing that, I was thinking: "Why am I trying to parse the value trough JSON, if I can just use a regular expression to test whether the input value complies with the NumericLiteral grammar." Hehe... Great answer!

Comment: Although I'll pass on the octNumber check, since octals are banned from numeric literals in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: But isn't the Function evaluation dangerous. I mean, the visitor could input a malicious value that when evaluated, could cause trouble. And it is not needed actually. I just figured that I don't really need to treat the input as s NumericLiteral. What I really wanted is to check whether the value complies to the NumericLiteral grammar... If the regexp check is passed, we can simply convert the value with `Number(value)`.

Comment: @Šime, The Function evaluation will occur *only* when the value complies with the `NumericLiteral` grammar, a malicious value will not pass the RegExp validation, IMO is not dangerous, since we have a good validation... About `Number(value)` you will have differences regarding `OctalIntegerLiteral`, but since you don't want octal literals should be Ok...

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. It's perfectly safe then. But I'll just return Number(value) since I only want the grammar check.